# How to add modified time to trac report

Tags: trac

I am trying to make modified time appear on trac report so I added change time to the sql query but now all I am getting is a long number in the modified column why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
select date(changetime, 'unixepoch') from ticket
```

from 
http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/2219

Since 0.12 trac uses [microsecond timestamps](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracUpgrade#Microsecondtimestamps), so you have to specify:

```
select date(changetime / 1000000, 'unixepoch') from ticket
```